# How to find the last 7 days Records in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I would like to know the past 7 days record. I want to write a query for that in where condition. I have very basic knowledge of sqlite. Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the date in one of the columns in your DB.  In my app I convert the NSDate (iPhone obviously) to a double for storing in the DB using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.  Given that I can query for a date range.

I wrote functions that calculate the NSDate for midnight X days in the past/future, which I use to determine the startDate and endDate of queries.  Here is an excerpt from the code that will give you some idea:

```
char selectQuery[MAX_STR];
sprintf(selectQuery, "SELECT DateTime FROM Journal WHERE DateTime >= %f AND DateTime < %f;", 
                     [startDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate],
                     [endDate   timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

I didn't want to convert NSDate to date time strings because I don't trust the conversions back and forth with all the various timezones and different locale's ways of formatting dates.

Comment: this is the actual query for java: select * from table_name where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',field_name)>=date('now','-6 days') and strftime('%Y-%m-%d',field_name)<=date('now') order by field_name desc;

Answer (score 1):

sqlite doesn't keep track of when your table rows were added. If you need this behavior you should add a timestamp column and set the current time in it when you insert a new row.

Comment: can i use the between clause? i mean select * from tablename order by columnname between currentdate and currentdate-7;

Comment: Between does not exist in sqlite. You can do SELECT * FROM tablename  WHERE columnname > currentdate - 60*60*24*7 ORDER BY columnname. You should look over the sqlite syntax: sqlite.org/lang.html. I am assuming you'll store the date as a UNIX timestamp

Comment: BETWEEN *does* exist in SQLite.